# How to display date in HH:mm:ss format in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using following code to generate chart in JasperReports.

```xml
<xyLineChart> 
    <chart evaluationTime="Band"> 
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="500"/> 
    </chart> 
    <xyDataset> 
        <dataset incrementType="None"/> 
        <xySeries> 
            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["CpuUsageGraph"]]></seriesExpression> 
            <xValueExpression><![CDATA[new Long($F{time}.getTime())]]></xValueExpression> 
            <yValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{cpuUsage}]]></yValueExpression>
        </xySeries> 
    </xyDataset> 
    <linePlot> 
        <plot/> 
    </linePlot> 
</xyLineChart>
```

I am printing the date on the X-axis, but it is displaying in milliseconds.
How do I display it in `hh:mm:ss` format?

Answer (score 18):

You can use following code in Java:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z").format($V{VAR_DATE})
```

where **$V{VAR_DATE}** is the date variable to be converted into the format.

Comment: What does the z in this stand for ?

Comment: 'z' stands for Time Zone. You can check here for more patterns - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just put the date variable in a text field and then, go the the properties view, and write this in the Pattern field: HH:mm:ss. It could be useful to also check the "Blank when null" checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Simply, You can add in `pattern` property of the text field of date.
the field should be in `java.sql.Date` format
You can write in `pattern` `HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1):

The property you are looking for is the "time axis tick label mask". There is no "pattern" field for a time series chart.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xyLineChart> 
    <chart evaluationTime="Band"> 
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="500"/> 
    </chart> 
    <xyDataset> 
        <dataset incrementType="None"/> 
        <xySeries> 
            <seriesExpression><![CDATA["CpuUsageGraph"]]></seriesExpression> 
            <xValueExpression><![CDATA[new Long($F{time}.getTime())]]></xValueExpression> 
            <yValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{cpuUsage}]]></yValueExpression>
        </xySeries> 
    </xyDataset> 
    <linePlot> 
        <plot/> 
    </linePlot> 
</xyLineChart>
```

> public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT ="yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
>   DateFormat df = new
>   SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
>   df.format($V{VAR_DATE})

Answer (score 0):

Specify the "Time Period" as "minute" under the 'details' section of the chart details.

```
timePeriod="Minute"
```

From JasperReports Ultimate Guide: Time Period Expression

> This expression returns a java.util.Date value from which the engine
>   will extract the corresponding time period depending on the value set
>   for the timePeriod attribute mentioned earlier in the Time Series
>   dataset. For instance, if the chart is about yearly data, the engine
>   will extract only the year from the date value, or if you are
>   gathering monthly data, the engine will use only the month value from
>   the date object returned by this expression.