# How to customize the format of the various label of X axis in the Time Series graph in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am working on iReport 3.7.3 . In that i am trying to design a Time Series Graph , i want to change the labels at x axis of the graph. My date values are in yyyy-mm-dd(2012-01-14) format but when it generates the graph i am getting value in MMM-yyyy(Jan-2012) format. Can you please suggest why this is happening and how can i customize it according to my need(Jan12)?

Comment: You can look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2643988/876298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the value axis tick label mask property to format dates by entering SHORT", "MEDIUM", "LONG" and "FULL" depending on what you need.

Comment: but is there any way i can print jan11 only , jan is month and 11 is year(2011)??

Comment: Thanx Scott. Got it.  I used MMMyy in that.